# Classic ASP script causing 'Type mismatch' error on new server

Tags: mysql, asp-classic, type-mismatch

I have just been forced to relocate a forum from an old Windows 2002 server to a new 2012 one.

It's an old classic ASP forum (snitz) that is 'vanilla' and has worked happily for years.

After figuring out the new connection string to get MySql to connect on this server, the forum is now throwing the following errors in places it really shouldn't

> Microsoft VBScript runtime  error '800a000d'
>
> Type mismatch
>
> /forum/inc_moderation.asp, line 74

It seems to be where it is checking a numeric value (assigned to a variable from a DB enquiry).  Here is the function from the above example:

```
function CheckForUnmoderatedPosts(CType, CatID, ForumID, TopicID)
    Dim PostCount
    PostCount = 0
    if strModeration > 0 then
        ' Check the Topics Table first
        strSql = "Select Count(*) as PostCount"
        strSql = strSql & " FROM " & strTablePrefix & "TOPICS T"
        if CType = "CAT" then
            strSql = strSql & " WHERE T.CAT_ID = " & CatID & " AND T.T_STATUS > 1 "
        elseif CType = "FORUM" then
            strSql = strSql & " WHERE T.FORUM_ID = " & ForumID & " AND T.T_STATUS > 1 "
        elseif CType = "TOPIC" then
            strSql = strSql & " WHERE T.TOPIC_ID = " & TopicID & " AND T.T_STATUS > 1 "
        elseif CType = "POSTAUTHOR" then
            strSql = strSql & " WHERE T.T_AUTHOR = " & MemberID & " AND T.T_STATUS > 1 AND T.TOPIC_ID = " & TopicID
        end if
        if CType = "BOARD" then
            strSql = strSql & ", " & strTablePrefix & "CATEGORY C"
            strSql = strSql & ", " & strtablePrefix & "FORUM F"
            ' This line makes sure that moderation is still set in the Category
            strSql = strSql & " WHERE T.CAT_ID = C.CAT_ID AND C.CAT_MODERATION > 0"
            ' This line makes sure that moderation is still set to all posts or topic in the Forum
            strSql = strSql & " AND T.FORUM_ID = F.FORUM_ID AND F.F_MODERATION in (1,2)" & " AND T.T_STATUS > 1 "
        end if
        set rsCheck = my_Conn.Execute(strSql)
        if not rsCheck.EOF then
            PostCount = rsCheck("PostCount")
        else
            PostCount = 0
        end if
        if PostCount = 0 then
            ' If no unmoderated posts are found on the topic table, check the replies.....
            strSql = "Select Count(*) as PostCount"
            strSql = strSql & " FROM " & strTablePrefix & "REPLY R"
            if CType = "CAT" then
                strSql = strSql & " WHERE R.CAT_ID = " & CatID & " AND R.R_STATUS > 1 "
            elseif CType = "FORUM" then
                strSql = strSql & " WHERE R.FORUM_ID = " & ForumID & " AND R.R_STATUS > 1 "
            elseif CType = "TOPIC" then
                strSql = strSql & " WHERE R.TOPIC_ID = " & TopicID & " AND R.R_STATUS > 1 "
            elseif cType = "POSTAUTHOR" then
                strSql = strSql & " WHERE R.R_AUTHOR = " & MemberID & " AND R.R_STATUS > 1 AND R.TOPIC_ID = " & TopicID
            end if
            if CType = "BOARD" then
                strSql = strSql & ", " & strTablePrefix & "CATEGORY C"
                strSql = strSql & ", " & strtablePrefix & "FORUM F"
                ' This line makes sure that moderation is still set in the Category
                strSql = strSql & " WHERE R.CAT_ID = C.CAT_ID AND C.CAT_MODERATION > 0"
                ' This line makes sure that moderation is still set to all posts or reply in the Forum
                strSql = strSql & " AND R.FORUM_ID = F.FORUM_ID AND F.F_MODERATION in (1,3)" & " AND R.R_STATUS > 1 "
            end if
            rsCheck.close
            set rsCheck = my_Conn.Execute(strSql)
            if not rsCheck.EOF then
                PostCount = rsCheck("PostCount")
            else
                PostCount = 0
            end if
        end if
        rsCheck.close
        set rsCheck = nothing
    end if
    CheckForUnModeratedPosts = PostCount
end function
```

Line 74 is:  **if PostCount = 0 then**

Why would that be causing a type mismatch?  It's not just this script - I managed to fix this one by putting a 'trim' on PostCount ( so changing it to):

```
if trim(PostCount) = 0 then
```

which fixes it, but then (many) other scripts are causing the same issue.

I have searched to the best of my abilities, but can't find anything else to try.
(the closest I found was this thread: [iis7, classic asp; type mismatch error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688793/iis7-classic-asp-type-mismatch-error) but I couldn't see how to make that applicable to my configuration)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143022/discussion-on-question-by-stevemid-classic-asp-script-causing-type-mismatch-er).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rolling back to 5.1 and using the following connection string solved the problem:

```
"driver=MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver;option=16387;server=localhost;uid=xxxxxxx;pwd=yyyyyyy;database=zzzzzzz"
```

To see how I reached this fix and get a better idea of what was going wrong, see the comments thread on my original post (in short, it looked like the database was returning a strange vartype from the DB's COUNT statement which couldn't be compared to an integer. This seems to be an ODBC driver issue as an older driver fixed this)

Comment: +1 Glad you got it working Steve, thanks for posting back to let us know what it is. Don't forget to accept the answer so the queue is cleared.

Comment: Given the ephemeral nature of comments, I wonder if you could add a summary of the comment thread to your answer.

Comment: `option=16387` is the key point. The option should contain `NO_BIGINT(16384)` flag, otherwise the return value type of `COUNT()` is BIGINT and cannot be handled by vbscript. See [mysql odbc option parameters](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-configuration-connection-parameters.html#codbc-dsn-option-flags)